# Macro definition

Tags: elisp-macros, filenames

I'm in the process of "modularizing" my config file and ran into a problem involving elisp macros.

Because of the way in which I'm defining my configuration modules, I ended up with a bunch of code blocks as the following:

```
(with-eval-after-load (expand-file-name
                       "latex.el"
                       j/config-path)
  (leader
    :infix "o"
    "e" '(ebib :which-key "ebib"))
  (some-function x y z))
```

Since I was repeting that a lot, I tried to define a macro to have more readable config files. It is my first time writing macros in elisp, so this was what I ended up with:

```
(defmacro j/con-load (module &rest funcs)
      "TODO doc goes here"
      `(with-eval-after-load
           (expand-file-name (concat ,module ".el" j/config-path))
         funcs))
```

I'm trying to call it with

```
(j/con-load "latex"
  (leader
    :infix "o"
    "e" '(ebib :which-key "ebib"))
  (some-function x y z))
```

but it just doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `pp-macroexpand-last-sexp` is your friend.  It shows you the code that your macro is expanding into, which is:

```el
(with-eval-after-load
    (expand-file-name
     (concat "latex" ".el" j/config-path))
  funcs)
```

Which tells Emacs to evaluate the variable `funcs` (which probably won't exist) should it ever load a library `</path/to/current/default-directory>/latex.el</value/of/j/config-path>` (which seems rather unlikely to ever occur).

@q.undertow has covered the `concat` usage.

For the rest, you probably wanted to *splice* your `&rest` argument into the expanded macro with `,@funcs` ?

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Backquote` for more about splicing.

Answer (score 3):

For one thing (and I am not at all sure there isn't another problem), the call to `expand-file-name` in the macro body is scrambled. It should be

```
(expand-file-name (concat ,module ".el") j/config-path)
```

Also you may want to evaluate the concatentation at macro expansion time:

```
(expand-file-name ,(concat module ".el") j/config-path)
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. As you said, there are more errors in my code, with this is one less thing to worry about.